# Fluid simulation baking

Tags: baking, fluid-simulation

I am experiencing issues while following an introduction to fluid simulation. When I try to bake my simulation, either Blender crashes with the error "Error: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION" after a few frames (21), either the baking continues after the frame 21 but the top surface of the mesh disappears (photo).

[image]

Do you have an idea to fix it ?

I already tried to uninstall Blender 2.79 and install other versions instead but it didn't help.

Config :
- i5 7400
- Gtx 1060 6GB 
- driver 391.1
- Windows 10

Comment: That sounds like a Blender bug. Can you share the Blender file so I can take a look at it?

Comment: Sure, here is the file : [beach.blend](https://we.tl/ErtJPg1s8B) . Baking the simulation should be enough to reproduce the bug.